# VLC Socket bind error at boot

Tags: networking, permissions, vlc, systemd, shairplay

Short: When run the script manually it works, at boot time i get the VLC error

> core access out error: socket bind error: Permission denied

---

I want to run a command at boot time, so I created a systemd script.

```
[Unit]
Description=Stars Shairport and VLC 

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=shairport-sync
Group=shairport-sync
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "sleep 5;shairport-sync | cvlc - --sout '#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:standard{access=http,mux=ogg,dst=192.168.4.147:8080}' --demux=rawaud --rawaud-channels=2 --rawaud-samplerate=44100"
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This Script is run as user shairport-sync, created like this (followd by a tutorial)

```
$ getent group shairport-sync &>/dev/null || sudo groupadd -r shairport-sync >/dev/null
$ getent passwd shairport-sync &> /dev/null || sudo useradd -r -M -g shairport-sync -s /usr/bin/nologin -G audio shairport-sync >/dev/null
```

When I execute the script manually everything is working fine. When I enable the Service to start at boot time I get the error messages below

```
sh[393]: [74001790] core access out error: socket bind error: Permission denied
sh[393]: [74001790] core access out error: cannot create socket(s) for HTTP host
sh[393]: [74001790] access_output_http access out error: cannot start HTTP server
sh[393]: [74000b28] stream_out_standard stream out error: no suitable sout access module for `http/ogg://192.168.4.147:8080'
sh[393]: [74000788] core stream output error: stream chain failed for `transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:standard{access=http,mux=...8.4.147:8080}'
sh[393]: [74200508] core input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting
```

When looking for open ports 8080 is not used yet.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i played around a bit and solved the problem myself.
When i change the Dst-IP from **192.168.4.147:8080** to **0.0.0.0:8080** VLC stops complaining and starts the service listening at 0.0.0.0:8080 without problems.